# Bluetooth device not listing in android oreo

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-8.0-oreo, android-ble

BLE devices like ESP 32 is not getting listed while using react-native-ble-manager on android applications with os version > 8 (oreo).

The same code works fine with android OS versions < 8 (oreo)

Answer (score 0):

The only major change that can be relevant to your issue is that in Android 8, the scan response data length has changed. Please have a look at the following link:-

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#bt

If your app is using background execution, there is also an update to the Background Execution limit. Have a look at this:-

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-samples#bel